# Auto add columns value to a textbox without click a button

Tags: vb.net

Datagridview table example:

```
ItemName      ItemPrice
Candy         20
Candy2        10

textbox1 30

ItemName      ItemPrice
Candy2        10

textbox1 10
```

What I wanted to say is that whenever I add a row into the table
it automatically calculate the item price in a textbox. So if I add another item
into the datagrid it will update automatically with the total sum of the itemprice column from the datagrid table. Also when I delete a row it also decrease the sum ,without pressing any button.

Comment: "So if I add another item into the textbox it will update automatically with the total sum of the itemprice column from the datagrid table". Don't you mean add another item into the datagridview ?

Comment: yes. my brain was somewhere while typing my explaination. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

CellValueChanged reacts after a change, there yoou can add arithmetic operations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Dieter Bauer it wasn't cellValueChanged but I got the idea with your suggestion. it was rowAdded event. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was "rowsAdded" event on Datagridview. when a new row is added to the datagrid it automatically put the price in the textbox as well as adding another row, it will show the total sum of how many rows are added.